# Cant add Tabs to Actionbar

Tags: tabs, android-actionbar

i just want to add tabs to the actionbar.
why do i get an error with this code?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    Tab tab1 = getActionBar().newTab();
    Tab tab2 = getActionBar().newTab();
    tab1.setText("tab1");
    tab2.setText("tab2");       
    getActionBar().addTab(tab1 );
    getActionBar().addTab(tab2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake i had no callback for the tab.
i had to insert .setTabListener() otherwise i get an error